# How can I say "Flash-forward"?

Tags: word-requests

I've been thinking about a way to say

> "Flash-forward two years in the future, he is now a school-teacher.

or something of the like.

> 二年後、彼は今教師です。

is what I thought of. Does this even make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 二年後、彼は今教師です。

It only means "After two years, he is now a school-teacher." It's present event.

Japanese vocabulary doesn't have the word "flash forward", because Japanese novelists have never invented it. If your intent is to find a rhetoric to describe the future as if it's already happened, there are several ways:

> 二年後、そこには教師になった彼の姿が（あった！）

I think it's a wording popularized by docudrama programs, so maybe sounds too TV trope.

> 二年後を見てみよう。彼は今教師だ。
>   二年後を見てみましょう。彼は今教師です。

That's not a fixed phrase. Just manually set the scene into the future, and you can continue your talk with present tense.

> 二年後、彼は教師になっている。
>   二年後、彼は教師になっています。

This one is a steady expression to tell determined future, but the viewpoint remains in present.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [expression](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=fast+forward+to+the+present):

> - fast-forward to the present:
>     早送りして現在を見てみる

Perhaps it can be modified to:

> - fast-forward to X year:
>     X年に早送りして見てみる
> - fast-forward by X years:
>     X年間早送りして見てみる

Some more tries (please edit/correct/comment if it's wrong or unnatural)

- 時計をX年進める